# A command fetching SVN revisions without comments

Tags: regex, svn, awk, sed, cut

How to get SVN revisions which are committed without `jira ticket#` in the comments?

```
 ------------------------------------------------------------------------
 r1 | user2 | 2006-11-22 02:13:42 -0500 (Tue, 22 Nov 2006) | 1 line
 Changed paths:
 M /trunk/testfile.txt

 added new file
------------------------------------------------------------------------
r2 | user 3 | 2006-11-22 02:08:37 -0500 (Tue, 22 Nov 2006) | 1 line
Changed paths:
M /trunk/testfile1.txt

added new file
------------------------------------------------------------------------
r3 | user 1| 2006-11-18 02:13:56 -0500 (Fri, 18 Nov 2006) | 1 line
Changed paths:
M /trunk/testfile5.txt

Jira_issue-123 added new file
```

Desired output:

```
r1
r2
```

Comment: Can you post a sample input and the output you'd like to see?

Comment: Edited the question now.

Answer (score 0):

**Parsing the log in XML format**

If you want to parse the log *reliably*, use the [`--xml`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.ref.svn.html#svn.ref.svn.sw.xml) option and a tool capable of XML parsing. I would recommend [`xmlstarlet`](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/).

For example, the following command lists the revision numbers:

```
svn log -q --xml | xmlstarlet sel -t -v '//logentry/@revision'
```

*Sample Output*

```
1771403
1771252
1771240
```

The XPath expression selects values of `revision` attributes from all (`//`) `logentry` elements in the document.

You can prefix the numbers with `r` as follows:

```
svn log -q --xml | xmlstarlet sel -T -t \
  -m '//logentry' -v 'concat("r", @revision)' -n
```

*Sample Output*

```
r1771403
r1771252
r1771240
```

The `xmlstarlet` command concatenates `"r"` with the `revision` attribute values for all `logentry` elements in the document.

**When `xmlstarlet` is not available**

You can resort to slightly less reliable parsing of the `svn log -q` output with the help of *grep*, if you cannot install `xmlstarlet` for some reason:

```
svn log -q | grep -o '^r[0-9]\+'
```

*Sample Output*

```
r1771403
r1771252
r1771240
```

The same using *sed*:

```
svn log -q | sed -e '/^[^r]/d; s/^\(r[0-9]\+\).*/\1/'
```

The first *sed* expression deletes (`d`) the line, if it doesn't match the pattern (if there is no `r` at the beginning of the line). The second expression replaces the line with the part matching the pattern between `\(` and `\)`.

The regular expression matches `r` at the beginning of the line (`^`) followed by one or more digits. The `-o` option instructs *grep* to print only matching parts.